# Calling web service from JavaScript not working except in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

I am calling a web service which is located on another host.
It is working fine in IE but not in FF,Opera etc..
Here is my code :

```
    if(xmlHttpReq.readyState == 0){
        xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
        xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpReq.status == 200) {
                var resultString = xmlHttpReq.responseXML;
                document.getElementById('webserviceresponsetext').value = resultString.text;
            }
        }
        xmlHttpReq.send(packet);
    }
}

var packet = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>' +  
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" '+
'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> '+
'<soap:Body>'+
'<authenticate xmlns="http://interfaces.service.webservices.webs.eic.com">" '+
'<ParameterName>abc</ParameterName>'+
'<ParameterName>1234</ParameterName>'+
'</authenticate></soap:Body>'+
'</soap:Envelope>';
```

This method just calls authenticate method and returns true/false if user abc is valid user or not.1234 is password for abc user.
Please help...
Thanks in advance...

I am getting this error in FF:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{cb5142f9-33a8-44ca-bc9d-60305ef7cea8} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Comment: How are you creating your XHR and what does the server's response look like?

Comment: server's response is null, with xmlhttp.status = 0 and ready state = 4

Comment: First guess: the variable packet isn't visible on .send(), or, second guess: your content-type is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want ajax to reliably work across browsers, I'd recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

It'll abstract away the complexity of dealing with the XmlHttpReq directly, give you a much cleaner syntax and work across all major browsers.

Have a look at [jQuery's ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for a start.

Your code could look similar to this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
  $(this).addClass("done");
 }
});
```

Comment: sorry but i can't use jquery and I need to resolve this using JS only